# sanitize wrong json format in python

Tags: python, json, syntax

I have a received a json file with some data, that I'm supposed to analyse. The data comes from a sql-database, thus, it is normally structured in tables. However, when I receive it it looks like this:

```
{'TimeStamp1': '2018-06-03 00:21:04', 'Owner1': 'Some owner', 'Description1': 'A description', 'TimeStamp2': '2018-06-03 00:22:15', 'Owner2': 'A new Owner', 'Description2': 'A new description'}
```

... And so on. So only one line/object with all the data and multiple keys with almost the same name. How can I concvert it in Python to something similar to a sql-setup or:

```
{'records':
   {'TimeStamp': '2018-06-03 00:21:04', 'Owner': 'Some owner', 'Description': 'A description'}, 
   {'TimeStamp': '2018-06-03 00:22:15', 'Owner': 'A new Owner', 'Description': 'A new description'}
}
```

And still guarantee that the right owner is on the same line as the associated time stamp and description? :)

Comment: so it just adding 1 to the number at the end of the column name?

Comment: Exactly @Jacobr365, and 2 after the column name in the second row, 3 after the column name in the third row and so on. So the row number is indicated in the column name/key instead of creating a new object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it. This can likely be optimized but it should do what you want and be pretty simple

```
def sanitize(d, keys):
    b = 0
    records = []

    #get  the highest numerical key
    for key in x.keys():
        cur_key_num = int(" ".join(re.findall("[1-9]+", key)))
        if cur_key_num > b:
            b = cur_key_num

    #go through key numbers 1 at a time
    for i in range(1, b+1):
        rec = {}

        #build a dictionary for each keynum
        for key in keys:
            rec[key] = d[key + str(i)]
        re cords.append(rec)

    return records
```

The function is used like this:

```
data = {'TimeStamp1': '2018-06-03 00:21:04', 'Owner1': 'Some owner', 'Description1': 'A description', 'TimeStamp2': '2018-06-03 00:22:15', 'Owner2': 'A new Owner', 'Description2': 'A new description'}
k = ['TimeStamp', 'Owner', 'Description']
r = sanitize(data, k)
```

and returns:

```
[{'Owner': 'Some owner', 'TimeStamp': '2018-06-03 00:21:04', 'Description': 'A description'}, {'Owner': 'A new Owner', 'TimeStamp': '2018-06-03 00:22:15', 'Description': 'A new description'}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to do a few modifications, since I discovered that some of the column names had numbers included in the name, hence, 'b' ended up being way too high. However, I made a workaround where I only look at the TimeStamp-key, which should be included in each row, and now it works like a charm :D